# Stack Exchange user profile is not changed as per Stack Overflow user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture

I changed [my Stack Exchange user profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/411877/shree) and chose option copy from Stack Overflow, but it has not changed my profile.

I discussed it on [tavern-on-the-meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and two users also confirmed that.

Confirmation [1](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8335806#8335806) and [2](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8336311#8336311).

I got a suggestion on the Tavern discussion:

> Maybe it takes time for all servers to pick up the change. Give it 6
>   to 8 hours.

It's more than 12 hour as I write this, but I still see my old profile.

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce here, so marking as resolved.